# An inequality for three iid random variables with a log-concave density

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

It was [previously shown](https://mathoverflow.net/a/396467/36721) that
$$H\ge cG,\tag{1}$$
where $c:=1/14334$,
$$G:=E|X-Y|,\quad H:=E|X-Y|-\tfrac12\,E|X+Y-2Z|,$$
and $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables with the same log-concave density.

It is clear that the constant factor $c=1/14334$ is not optimal.

> **Question:** What is the best (that is, the largest) possible constant factor $c$ in (1)?

The following might turn out to be of help:

> **Conjecture:** The best possible value of $c$ is $1/9$, attained when $X$ has an exponential distribution (which would thus represent the least favorable case).

Comment: I am looking for a good answer as well! Thanks for "crosslink" my question!